# Jmeter JSONs comparison

Tags: jmeter

Currently I am working on moving some API DDT (data from CSV) tests from RobotFramework to Jmeter and what troubles me is the lack of proper JSONs assertion which is able to ignore some keys during comparison. I am totally new to jmeter so I am not sure if there's no such option available.

I am pretty sure we are using the wrong tool for this job, especially because functional testers would take the job of writing new tests. However, my approach (to make it as easy as possible for functionals) is to create jmeter plugin which takes response and compare it to baseline (excluding ignored keys defined in its GUI). What do you think? Is there any builtin I can use instead? Or do you know anything about some existing plugin?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's JSON Assertion:http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion

Answer (score 1):

The "proper" assertion is [JSON Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) available since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)

You can use arbitrary [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries to [filter response](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) according to your expected result

Example:

[image: JMeter JSON Path Assertion]

If it is not enough - you can always go for [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion), Groovy language has [built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) so it will be way more flexible than any existing or future plugin.

Comment: Wow, cool the new JMeter version 4.0. I missed the release till now :-)

Comment: Actually the equivalent [plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) exists for quite a while, you can install it to your current JMeter version using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) if you need to stay on previous for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the approach that I can think of:-

1. Take the response/HTML/json source code dump for the base line using "save response to a file".
2. Take the response dump for the AUT that needs to be compare or simply 2nd run dump.
3. Use 2 FTP sampler's to make calls for the locally saved response dump's.
4. Use compare assertion to compare the 2 FTP call response's.  In the compare assertion, you can use RegEx String and Substitution to mask the timestamps or userID to something common for both so that it will be ignored in comparison.

Below I have shown just an image for my thought's for help.

You need to take care on how to save and fetch the response's.

[image]

Hope this help.